# Use FileSystem Object to telnet an IP and some questions

Tags: variables, vbscript, telnet

I´ve post another question here that was to get my external IP and then telnet it to a device.

With the huge help from the user Matt, i've managed to do that successfully, but now i have some questions on how to improve and change the code. My code is has followed:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objHTTP : Set objHTTP = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp")
objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://icanhazip.com", False
objHTTP.Send

On Error Resume Next

Dim WshShell

set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.run "cmd.exe"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "telnet domain.com 9999"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "p"

WshShell.SendKeys "a"

WshShell.SendKeys "s"

WshShell.SendKeys "s"

WshShell.SendKeys "w"

WshShell.SendKeys "o"

WshShell.SendKeys "r"

WshShell.SendKeys "d"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "1"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

Function IPAddressToCharArray(pIpAddress)
    Dim intCounter
    Dim intLen
    Dim singleCharacter
    Dim strFormattedIpAddress
    Dim arrChars()

    ' Remove the periods
    ' strFormattedIpAddress = Replace(pIpAddress,".","")

    ' Set the array length
    intLen = Len(strFormattedIpAddress)-1
    redim arrChars(intLen)

    ' Cycle through the string
    For intCounter = 0 to intLen
        ' Capture the current character.
        arrChars(intCounter)  = Mid(strFormattedIpAddress, intCounter + 1,1)
    Next

    IPAddressToCharArray = arrChars
End Function

For Each strSingleCharacter in IPAddressToCharArray(objHTTP.ResponseText)
    WshShell.SendKeys strSingleCharacter
Next 

Set objWSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Sleep 2000

objWSHShell.SendKeys objHTTP.ResponseText

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WScript.Quit 

Set objHTTP  = Nothing
```

First question - i've read in this forum to run from sendkeys like the plague, which i kind off agree, but what is the alternative, since that telnet can only be written by typing keys, or is there a command i can send without typying simulation?

Second question - in my example i have one telnet session. Can i have other telnet sessions being issued one after the other, meaning when one finish, the other star, in this same scrpt, or do i need to create different files for each telnet session and then issu them?

Third - Is there a way to telnet commands through sendkeys (if another way is not found) but in the background, so in case i press something out the window that opens, it doesn't start to send keys to anothet windows?

Thank you in advance to anyone or all that can help me.

Comment: I cant speak for this as i only used it once many years ago but [here](http://tech.dimac.net/default3.asp?M=FreeDownloads/Menu.asp&P=FreeDownloads/FreeDownloadsstart.asp) is an activeX control that you can use. Documentation is [here](http://www.dimac.net/Products/FreeProducts/w3Sockets/Reference/Refstart.htm)

Comment: An example of what im suggesting is [here](http://www.teknoglot.se/code/vbs/w3socket-in-vbscript/)

Comment: Matt again to the rescue :), which question does your comment refers to? I asked three questions so i don't really know. Anyway i'm looking to what you provided, if i understand it until you're next comment, i'll replace or erase this comment.

Comment: This would almost answer all your questions. More the first and, if that works, the third. As for the second you just need to run the same  steps over again. Have a good look at the links i sent you. There are other solutions like that one but other are paid or have less documentation.

Comment: Well Matt, i'll try to look closer at the links you provided, but has for the second question i was tinking about having variables that woulg store several domain names, and then through a var=var+1 loop would telnet every variable until the last one would be reached. This way i wouldn't have to repeat several telnets in the code. I'm going to give a look at the codes you provided me in my other question related with the division of a variable into chars and the loop process, and see if i can fit with this ideia, but if you think of something, please let me know.